# Install OS on bare metal system without physical access

Tags: debian, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a cluster of computers in a data center remotely and we have been given the `root` access politically and technically. However, they are using RedHat and we want to install Debian on it and have the capability to “reimage” them if we need to, without the dependence on anyone else.

I don’t know how can I wipe out RedHat and install Ubuntu on it without physical access.

I am also okay if it is a one time physical access required and we don’t need to access it every time we want to re-image our Ubuntu os afterwards.

**Note**: In the end, those boxes are from HP and they have the iLO - lights out system where in the end. They have a control console that you can access the BIOS level control and even initiate a cold boot, reset, power off, etc… which I can install OS by using virtual media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note**: In the end, those boxes are from HP and they have the iLO - lights out system where in the end. They have a control console that you can access the BIOS level control and even initiate a cold boot, reset, power off, etc… which I can install OS by using virtual media.

You can do it from your home/office.

### Remote console (do it youself)

iLO allows you to use a virtual remote serial console to perform the installation. You might need to get a demo license code for running the installation once.

The remote console is accessible at the iLO web interface once you get the Admin password, which is printed on a stick inside the chassis.

[image: HPE iLO front end]

[image: Boot up]

For the image above, please trust me that you can either display the OS or run the installer if you boot from USB, DVD or virtual media

### Intelligent provisioning

I don't have this feature on my own Microserver, but I found some HPE hardware that ship with Intelligent Provisioning. This is a Linux-base firmware OS that allows you to install a supported OS by inserting the media and have the firmware do most of the dirty job. Not sure if it works with with Ubuntu.

As Intelligent Provisioning is not a real OS environment (e.g. it runs pre-POST) you don't need a license

Answer (score 4):

You would need some sort of [Out of band management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) system to do this properly. This would give you remote access over the network even without an OS or hard disk. Most computers in a data center have this sort of thing, but you will need to talk to the provider or whomever set up the boxes initially to get the details on how to use it.

Comment: Agreed with this answer, but another thing to keep in mind is that you could either request, or install your own (if they'll let you), a KVM-over-IP system (which is a type of out of band management), and then from that point forward, assuming the KVM-over-IP continues to work without error, you won't need further "IT" help to reimage the boxes. But you'll need one KVM-over-IP per box unfortunately, unless you have a special one that can do multiple boxes. (I am not disagreeing with your answer, just adding more detail to help the OP.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd review the physical (or kvm-over-ip) access options and based on that look into the following:

1. Setup PXE boot with kickstart on one of servers to re-image remaining servers to debian upon reboot. This will require lots of testing, at least one machine should have prolonged KVM access. Note, that this typically involves setting up a DHCP server, this might not be allowed in your data center environment.
2. With no physical access at all, look into virtualization options, ie depending on RedHat version and your familiarity, install KVM, Xen, OpenVZ or Docker on your RedHat hosts and create debian Virtual Machines for your purposes.